# Not able to pass basic auth headers in a dynamic curl cmd

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to run a dynamically generated `curl` command with basic authorization headers and store response code in a variable.
below is my shell script. (say `test.sh`)

```
auth="--header 'Authorization: Basic abcdefghijkl'"
url="http://localhost:8080"

cmd="curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w \"%{http_code}\" -X GET ${url} ${auth}"
echo $cmd
code=$($cmd)
echo $code
```

but above command doesn't send the authorization header in the GET request.

To demonstrate it I have written a small nodejs http server and logging headers in it, see below.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.write('This is a sample response from server.\n');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);

console.log("Server is listening on port 8080");
```

but on running `test.sh` via

```
bash test.sh
```

I get below output in shell:

```
"200""000""000"
```

and on server side i get below text in logs.

```
{ host: 'localhost:8080', 'user-agent': 'curl/7.54.0', accept: '*/*' }
```

There are two problems:

1. Basic auth header is not received on the server side.
2. Instead of 200 status-code I get `"200""000""000"` which is unexpected.

Can you please suggest what am i missing here?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The way you're invoking curl is kinda peculiar.

Try `curl --user name:password http://www.example.com` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: The command is not being executed properly (because it's stored in a simple variable). `IFS` causes `'Authorization:`, `Basic`, and `abcdefghijkl'` to be treated as separate arguments. `curl` interprets the last two as urls (they will fail to resolve and account for the two sets of `000`). You could use a function, array, or eval as described in [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: @guest Yes It does. Thanks.